# Should I downvote a self-answer if it doesn't work for me?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, wrong-answers

A user has answered their own question with a solution that they claim works for them, and their self-answer has been upvoted. However, I haven't been able to get their solution to work for me no matter how hard I try.

What should I do? Should I downvote it?

Comment: This question seems familiar somehow...

Comment: On the main site seeing a question disappearing then reappearing under another name would make me wonder if sock puppet.... but.... yeah now I'm just confused

Comment: @Patrice Someone else posted this, but I guess they self-deleted before the answer could be posted, so they made a self-answer.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Oh for sure. I understand that :p it's just ironic that a behavior I normally would've flagged as potential abuse comes from Boltclock :P I am convinced it's exactly as you say. I just find it funny

Comment: @Patrice: OR IS IT?!

Comment: @BoltClock You're doing this for extra rep, aren't you?!

Comment: @Patrice: it's badges. It's always for them badges!

Comment: Strangely relevant http://xkcd.com/1722/

Comment: Have you considered hiring a developer?

Comment: The tooltip of the downvote button is "Was not helpful" - so yes, of course, downvote.

Comment: A not quite [meta-tag:faq]?

Comment: @Braiam Lots of developers regularly read XKCD... strange I guess.

Comment: @u8y7541 well, it was released today...

Comment: @Braiam Exactly.

Comment: People have done it to me. 2 years after the original question/answer. :P

Comment: @BoltClock - why do you see a self-answer as something to treat different than other answers?

Comment: @4386427: I'm not asking you to treat the self-answer any differently to other answers. I'm saying if an asker claims something worked for them, when it clearly doesn't based on the question, then something is wrong with either the question or the answer, which needs to be addressed - and only the asker can do that, so give them the benefit of the doubt and allow them to clear things up. If they don't, or you're sure they're wrong on all accounts, vote as you do. It's the same reason why the "requires MCVE" and "unclear" close reasons exist - they're designed with the question asker in mind.

Comment: haha - why would you self-answer if it does not work for you?

Comment: @Zeeshan Mahmood: This question is about when you see *someone else's* self-answer, not your own.

Answer (score 55):

When a user self-answers with a solution that works for them, but you can't get it to work for you, this can mean one of a number of things:

- The poster is lying through their teeth.
- The poster's answer works for them because of critical information they have access to that they've withheld from their question (and, therefore, you).
- They messed up, resulting in a misleading answer that if *they* attempted to reproduce, would fail.
- They didn't mess up; you did. Make doubly sure you're reproducing the problem and solution correctly. It goes both ways.

If the problem was transient and neither the question nor the answer is going to be useful to anyone else, vote to close the question accordingly, and forget about it. Whether the answer is correct or wrong according to anyone is irrelevant.

If this is a more typical question, vote to close the question as not reproducible + requires MCVE, or unclear, or some other appropriate reason. Most likely, the question is missing critical information required to answer it correctly — this information needs to be in the question.

If you are *sure* that the self-posted solution cannot possibly work for anyone including the user themself no matter the circumstances, feel free to downvote their answer and leave a comment or post an answer debunking it.

Comment: If you cannot get this to work for you on the main site, feel free to try it here and post what does work for you.

Comment: Someone doesn't need to be *lying* to post a bad answer that they honestly think is correct.  Their answer can be unclear, have major security (or other tangential) problems, be incomplete, etc.  Likewise, they could easily be mistaken about the fact that a given approach has solved their problem.  It happens all the time.

Comment: It's also possible the person trying to use the solution is missing something, and that is the reason the solution does not work for them.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara: I was going to add "You messed up." to the list but... I'll add it now.

Comment: This answer does not work for me (just kidding, +1).

Comment: @Renan: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: At least half point of posting a question is to receive an answer. If you have a better one, then you should share it. It is very common that people will self-answer with something that "worked" for them, but is not an optimal solution. Or even a good solution. Even if they don't appreciate your sharing a better approach, someone else inevitably will. (That said, it seems this answer has shifted the focus from the answer to the question. Why would you close a question as "not reproducible" or "unclear" because a self-answer doesn't work or is invalid?)

Comment: @Cody Gray: The system clearly favors the asker's whims no matter what the policies tell you about votes, and user contributions being "owned" by the community (c.f. answer acceptance). So the least you could do, when in doubt, is assume the asker honestly has it right and they just messed up somewhere in their question, if not their answer, and let them clear things up. If you're sure that the asker is in over their head then by all means post.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Just do whatever you feel is right.

Comment: It's also possible the answer depends on information the not in the question, but the question could have been answered with a more generic answer without it. This usually the kind of self-answer I see.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to [BoltClock's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332793/1536976) very nice answer:

It could also be that you have a slightly different problem and just aren't aware of it yet (different OS, different software version, different anything...).

This is the no-one messed up but you still cannot reproduce the solution case.

Instead of close voting you might then want to check other answers (if available) and comment on the self answered, not working answer.

If you ever identify what makes your problem slightly different you could post your own question about it. Do not forget to include what makes your problem different though.

Comment: Or post your answer to the slight variation on the same question.  If your searching got you there, probably someone else's searching will, too.

Comment: Many of these cases call for editing the original question to distinguish it from the new one -- for instance, if it claims a behavior common to Python but that only happens on 3.x.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing special about self-answered questions. Question should be up to SO standards and answers should answer question as asked. Vote according to content and not author of the posts.

My recommendation:

If you *have a problem* and found matching question - feel free to downvote answers that does not solve the problem (after verifying that your problem matches the question see [BoltClock's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332793/477420)). Definitely provide comments and consider own answer when you get one (or duplicate vote).

If you *idly browsing* SO and found such Q&A pair - avoid downvoting unless you are sure there is no way solution ever worked. There is good chance that when problem encountered in real life solution is actually useful. Definitely consider commenting.

If you just *following posts by particular user* - stop now, don't downvote as this will likely be "targeting a user" (which may trigger serial-downvote reversal and if repeated hopefully will get attention of moderators).

Comment: Fully agree with the first part. Voting (down as well as up) shouldn't depend on the author but solely on quality of the answer (/question)