# Question and answer are all messed up

Tags: discussion

[This guy posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025916/div-class-logo-isnt-showing?noredirect=1#comment65461115_39025916), then stated in a comment under an answer that that answer didn't solve the problem but helped him solve it. But he didn't post the solution.

When I complained to him about that, he edited his original question to show the solution while deleting the original problem code!

So I complained to him again, which he took issue with, but posted his solution while accepting the other answer as the solution but not his own.

So we don't know what the original problem code is and a visitor will be confused by the accepted solution. This is all screwed up and, personally, I'd just delete the whole thing.

I added a note to the accepted answer but I'm not sure that was the right thing to do.

Comment: I don't understand. I already rolled back the edits introducing the answer inside the question itself, and the OP further edited it, well before you asking this question. What is the issue here?

Comment: @Tunaki Yes, well before I asked the question here. The problem occurred yesterday and I gave him a chance to fix what he did.

Comment: There is no need for ceremony, bad code goes above the line and good code below.  Just rollback the edit, no comment required.  If he keeps editing then flag a moderator.

Comment: I have removed the note. Don't edit commentary into an answer. It shouldn't be there and moves us onto a slippery slope where people edit random commentary into posts for whatever reason they see fit. I know you have the best intentions there, but it won't end well.

Comment: Just realized this is basically the reverse of my recent self-answered question [Should I downvote a self-answer if it doesn't work for me?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332792/should-i-downvote-a-self-answer-if-it-doesnt-work-for-me) - in which case, everything I said there applies.

Answer (score 2):

Other than feeling compelled to post the solution in the accepted answer incorporated with their own trivial<sup>1</sup> changes to their original code, I'm hard-pressed to find an actionable behavioral problem here (the drawn-out comment thread comes close, but I've wiped it now). Had the asker accepted their own answer, someone else might have complained that they weren't giving the other answer credit (and there have been a number of such complaints here on meta, although of course the site search sucks and I can't find any of them right now), which would have been worse. At least they acknowledged the other answer by accepting it, which is something.

I agree that the asker's self-answer simply doesn't need to exist, since the changes they made are trivial and irrelevant to the problem at hand anyway, making their answer minus those changes therefore essentially nothing more than a carbon copy of the other answer. But don't treat it like one. You can tell them their changes are irrelevant, and vote based on that, but if you were to flag it as a copy of the other answer I can't guarantee it will be deleted.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I have a sneaking suspicion that the changes were not actually trivial, but since the asker refuses to tell us anything I'll just assume they are.</sub>