# If the author says it's not an answer, can we take their word for it?

Tags: feature-request, not-an-answer

There are thousands of answers containing the phrases like "not an answer", and my knee-jerk impulse is to trust the author, and flag it.

Seems like it would be cool if there was an automated check when posting an answer, looking for common patterns of this sort (phrases like "[Not an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%22not+an+answer%22)", "[doesn't really answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%22doesn%27t+really+answer%22)", "[answer your question, but](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%22answer+your+question+but%22)", etc.), and warn the author that if they don't think it's an answer, maybe they shouldn't post it?

To clarify, I'm not calling for all of these to be deleted, I'm only suggesting a warning be displayed.

Comment: The irony is that flagging any of those as NAA gets the flag (rightfully) rejected because they are actual attempts at answering. I like how most of them are users with quite a lot of reputation as well.

Comment: @Keiwan - Yes, that's true in a fair number of cases, and in the perfect world that *may* only exist in my head, those people would then take another look at their answer and say: "You know, this is a valid attempt to answer the question, and I feel good about it, so I will remove this needlessly insecure disclaimer now."

Comment: Hey man, don't mess with my needlessly insecure disclaimer! I mean, you know, if that's okay with you.

Comment: @Keiwan They are *by definition* not attempts to answer the question, because the author has unequivocally stated that they feel it's not an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Servy Maybe some of them but for the majority I read it as: "If this attempt works then take it as an answer, if not, then I never claimed it was an actual answer anyway." They might feel like it doesn't fully answer the question but that doesn't change the fact that they're still attempting to answer something. Some of them also present an alternative way of solving the underlying problem which quite often ends up being useful as well.

Comment: @Keiwan Again, it's not a "maybe".  If the author has explicitly stated that they are not attempting to answer to the question, then they're not attempting to answer the question, unless you think they're lying (why do you think they'd lie about that though?)

Comment: @Servy So are you saying they should theoretically all qualify for the NAA flag?

Comment: @Keiwan I'd certainly need a pretty compelling reason not to.

Comment: @Servy The flag is essentially just a way to get those posts deleted. What about [upvoted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41581349/6214222) and [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/336001/6214222) (and therefore actually useful) "answers"? Or a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27731529/6214222) that benchmarks the given solutions, which I would definitely consider a loss of value if it were to be deleted.

Comment: @Keiwan The first two seem like *really* bad answers.  They're just code dumps with nothing else added other than a statement that they're not an answer.  If they aren't answers, then what *are* they?  They don't even tell the reader what they do, other than that they apparently aren't answering the question.  For the last I don't really see any value there at all.  If anyone actually cares to know how a given answer performs, it's easy enough to run the program, and it's unequivocally Not An Answer in every sense of the word.

Comment: Shoot, [I've done this myself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169510/running-junit-tests-in-a-swing-gui-using-swing-worker) when I've wanted to post a code base that might help the user solve the problem or improve the question (see the link above for example), and when I've done this, I've made my "answer" a community wiki. I have to ask, is that wrong?

Comment: Odd, I see so many answers that utterly fail to answer the question but don't explicitly say so.  Not hard to knee-jerk either.  Give the guy a freakin' medal for being truthful in the help he provides, no point in hating it.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I mean, that answer doesn't really provide much of a resolution. As the asker states, the problem was resolved elsewhere. But the question itself doesn't have much closure (even though it's considered "answered" now). And I'm not talking about voting to close.

Comment: @BoltClock: I don't disagree at all.

Comment: @Keiwan, that's how I read it too. Sometimes -- especially from someone with high reputation -- "this doesn't answer your question" can be a hint that the question itself is flawed. I've had a question or two where a "non-answer" highlighted that I was going about the problem the wrong way. So... doesn't answer what I asked, answers what I _should have_ asked.

Comment: @Servy There's plenty of cases where somebody thinks they're giving a valid answer and they're actually not. Don't see why the inverse couldn't occur.

Comment: @BenAaronson What reason is there to lie though and claim that they weren't trying to answer the question when they actually were?  There are lots of reasons to lie and say you *are* trying to answer the question (you don't want your non-answer deleted) but what reason is there to lie and say you *aren't* trying to answer the question, and attempting to trick people into deleting  your answer that you actually feel is trying to answer the question?

Comment: @Servy - They aren't lying. They sincerely believe (sometimes mistakenly) that they are not answering *the literal question being asked*. Or even that they are not providing a "real" answer. But none of that matters. It still might be an answer. Suppose I built a four-wheeled vehicle, with an engine, transmission, suspension, steering mechanism, and brakes, and told you "it's not a car". Is it a car? What if I point to a Toyota Corolla in the parking lot and tell you "that's not a car". Is it a car? Come on, Servy. An answer is an answer. Doesn't matter if (or why!) anyone says it's not.

Comment: @Servy: Weren't you [on the other side of the argument](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332792/should-i-downvote-a-self-answer-if-it-doesnt-work-for-me/332793#comment385411_332793) before?

Comment: @John Y: Only if it identifies as one.

Comment: @BoltClock How does that comment contradict any of the statements that I've made here?

Comment: I often find when the question suffers from the XY problem I will give a little disclaimer that my answer does not answer the question as read. "How should I best bash my head with a hammer?" might get the response "You shouldn't do that at all.". Which does not answer the question but is useful regardless. Is that an answer or not?

Comment: I think the core of the issue is that the term "answer" on SO does not mean the same thing as answer in general English. And these comments are meant in the latter meaning while the close reason is the earlier meaning

Comment: I think I've done this once or twice... I've seen it when a user, usually with low rep, asks the complete wrong question. If you know very little about the subject, it's hard to ask a good question. I don't see what harm there is in answering what you think they're trying to ask.

Comment: "Not an answer" can be an important caveat (and talisman against downvotes for incompleteness) when your contribution is more than a comment, but only solves one aspect of the problem, reduces but does not eliminate the problem, or even just (fails to) replicate a problem in some informative way.  Something like:  "On *other_version*, I get *following_output*, with or without *red_herring* enabled.  As you can see, Problem Part 1 has vanished, but Problem Part 2 is still there, and New Weirdness has appeared.  So this looks like both a *your_version* problem as well as *speculation*..."

Comment: If this comment is helpful, it was written by Robert Columbia. If it isn't, I don't know who wrote it.

Comment: Common usages I see: "*This is not an answer, but was too long for a comment.*" and "*This is not an answer, but you could get started by `DoingStuff()`.*"

Answer (score 49):

I think that the answer by @Makoto (now deleted, so only visible to 10k users) is focusing on situations where the author of the question has stated that the answer is not an answer in the comments of that answer. Based on the links provided in your question and my interpretation of the question itself, it seems like you're actually asking about *answers* that contain text along the lines of "this isn't an answer" or similar.

In that case, the answer is the same. I have seen quite a few instances of this, and surprisingly, it usually turns out that the answer *is* an answer *(as defined in the help center)*, but the author of the answer does not believe that it answers the question completely.

In either case, the correct course of action is to handle each post on a case by case basis. I do not think that warning the user before-hand is going to have any benefit, because the people we want to stop from posting non-answers are just going to ignore the warning, and the people who would otherwise post useful content but don't feel that their answer completely answers the question could be discouraged from doing so.

Comment: I agree, and unfortunately it can sometimes require familiarity with the technology in question - "This isn't an answer but you have an indentation mismatch in line xx" *could* actually be the thing that solves the problem for a piece of Python code, but in most everything else is probably irrelevant and should have been a comment....

Comment: @Ajean not as often as you might think. We (me and a couple others from the SOCVR) went through the "not an answer" query last year at some point, and found that quite a few of the ones we sampled were actually answers, and didn't need to be comments. Remember that partial answers are OK, and sometimes really useful.

Comment: I didn't intend to imply that most were comments, just the one example I wrote above. I agree that each needs to be looked at individually.

Comment: @Ajean That specific response should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 23):

There are a couple reasons I can imagine the phrase being used.

First, when the response doesn't answer exactly what was asked, but addresses something behind that. I've had questions where I was approaching a situation in a bad way (which is why it was hard to solve!) and the 'non-answer' answered what I *should have* asked, giving me a better approach to the underlying need.

"How do I implement this solution?", versus "how do I solve this problem?"

Second, sometimes an answer is incomplete (doesn't solve for *all* cases), but might be complete enough to answer the current need, or can give hints as to avenues to pursue. It's not an answer, but can lead to one from either the original questioner or someone else in the audience. Discarding it at first opportunity because it's 'not an answer' could be a disservice to all involved.

For that matter, discarding it after an 'actual answer' is found might also be a disservice, in case the first answer isn't what someone else needs when they have a similar question. I don't know about everyone else, but when I come to SO or SE to solve a problem I usually read enough of each answer to see which one best suits my version of the problem posed by the questioner.

Answer (score 14):

I have had questions answered with phrases like "This doesn't answer your question, but" followed by how I was asking the wrong question and how it really does solve the overall problem I'm having. Just because I get focused on a single solution doesn't mean I have the correct understanding of the problem. As such, if someone wants to give me an answer that doesn't answer my question but rephrases the problem and answers THAT question - I think that is a good thing.

Answer (score 7):

I think the statement "This is not an answer" is irrelevant, no different from "Thank you" or "Please help me".  The answer itself is either an answer, or not an answer, on its own merits.

If it's an answer?  Edit out the meaningless phrase, and probably leave a comment letting the OP know why you did that.

If it's not an answer?  Flag NAA, and again probably leave a comment letting the OP know where not-answers belong (chat, comments, a blog post, whatever, depending on what it actually is).

I don't think a warning is needed.  It would be too hard to get a proper warning anyway that didn't have false negative and false positive rates both at unacceptable levels; and unless it was a hard stop (prohibits posting the content), it would probably be ignored anyway - if the poster thinks it's not an answer, and knows to say that, the poster probably knows they shouldn't be posting the not-answer.

Answer (score 6):

I believe I have seen several cases where

1. the answer *is* an answer, although sometimes a bit overly complex and a rather **abstract**, maybe using pseudocode.
2. The poster **wanted to get an entire code snippet written for him**, ready to use without understanding.

It is not an answer if the question is "please write this code for me", but then it maybe is not a good question... The abstract, theoretical answer is the answer to the better question. (Unless of course, you program only by copy&paste from SO... which seems to become increasingly popular...) I believe in many cases where the answer "is not an answer" we should rather improve the question.

Answer (score 6):

Meh.

I'll occasionally use the answer section for an extended comment that simply won't work in a comment, e.g., with code, or large chunks of commentary not directly related to the question but that are still important to bring up. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8354753/438992, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8457497/438992, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318311/438992.

I don't do it as much as I used to, but sometimes *I* believe stuff is important enough that a link to a gist is too likely to be counted as noise and ignored. In most cases, particularly code cleanup, I explicitly don't want to edit the question because the comparison between the code is important (and it may make assumptions that aren't in the cleanup).

These "answers" could be deleted, and it's fine if they are, but IMO SO is a learning resource. Since there's no mechanism to supports such "answers" this seems the best, if dubious, solution.

A warning is fine, but I've already put the warning in the "answer" and made it clear that it's secondary input. IMO if the asker cared they'd edit the question to address the secondary concerns, but sometimes that makes no sense as then other legitimate answers would no longer make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Some may be actual even if useful comments, but cannot fit in comment presentation.

I have already done that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33999136/3545273). At the time of writing it, it was really a comment ala *what happens if you ...*. I honestly thought (and still think) that is could just use OP to narrow its problem, **what comments are made for**. Simply as it contained too much code I had to write it as an answer. I would not have been surprised just getting another comment just saying *didn't help*, and precisely did not want it to be flagged as NAA, before OP could use it. But I would have deleted it in that case.

Another and probably better example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30808615/3545273). Even if it is too long for a comment, it really does not answer the question: just a hint saying *this can help to understand the problem*. I really say **understand** and not **fix** here. Even if it was accepted, OP posted the real solution in its own post.

In that case, I do not think that flagging them as NAA will improve the site. But probably and as they were useful the disclaimer *not (really) and answer* could (should?) be removed.

As per your actual question, about a warning *Why do you post it as an answer it you think it is not one?*, I am not sure it would help much more here. Had I got such a warning, I would simply have not posted anything in both case.