# Can we get a lock on this suggested spam edit magnet answer please?

Tags: support, answers, specific-answer, locked-posts

See the [revision history of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23503186/timeline): it has been the target of spam editing every week since May 2016. There are quite a few approvals on that, hopefully by robo reviewers, but one person even approved two of these edits.

This answer should be locked to prevent such suggestions altogether.

As a side-statistic:

- 63 edits were suggested on this post
- 185 rejection votes have been cast (3 have been rejected with less than 3 votes due to a moderator vote)
- 10 approval votes have been cast.

That's little over 5% of approval votes on this kind of spam edit. Seems rather high to me.

Comment: May I propose a lifetime review ban for each user who had approved one of these edits? They obviously don't want to review correctly, so we don't need them in the review queues. Or does the moderation handle approving spam like approving a useless formatting edit (with the usual ban times)?

Comment: But that honeypot, though...

Comment: Strange, considering how few views the question gets.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: This would not be the only post of its kind. There are a number of extremely obscure (and, for some reason, usually not high quality) posts that are constantly hammered by spam edits. Your guess is as good as mine as to why.

Comment: @Tom: I'd love to hand out permanent review bans if I could. Unfortunately, the system does not allow that. We're supposed to give reviewers a chance, or something. Yeah, give them a chance to abuse the review queues and deliberately damage the quality of the site. That's reasonable.

Comment: @BoltClock even if they approve that edit twice? You might at least send them a long-term ban if you can't permanently ban them, with a stern warning not to approve spam edits.(I'd rather not link to the user here, you can find it in the revision history)

Comment: @BoltClock I also would give them a chance if the edit wasn't so obivously bad, but this here? Looks like the ban system is flawed :(.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Make that a feature request and I'll upvote it. It shouldn't be for one approval though; everybody can mis-click. But let's say, Approving 3 spam edits in a month. As it affects all sites on the network, I suggest posting it on MSE rather than MSO.

Comment: WTF at those "accepts"

Comment: Even [Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13385503) knew that was a bogus edit.

Comment: As to why: Keywords in the post URL? This post happens to contain the word "guestbook", for instance, and guestbooks are frequently targeted by spammers…

Comment: "Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot likes to keep an air of mystery about them" -- or a mysterious odor.

Comment: Sand before pearls, Spolsky strikes again...

Comment: @S.L.Barth Thanks for suggesting that there be some tolerance; I've fat-fingered reviews more than once.

Comment: Nice list of robo-reviewers you can get by seeing who approved those edits. The good news is that only one of those 8 robo-reviewers has the Steward badge (or maybe it's bad news because the others might still be approving spam).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

We have introduced a recent measure to help against suggested edit spam.

We were wondering why even spam via suggested edits, given they get rejected and it occurred to [Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1438/jon-ericson) that what spammers need is a place to point their clients to in order to show that the paid for spam is on a publicly available page, which, in this case is the review queue item for the suggested edit.

We've put it measures to stop that (not going into detail, for obvious reasons).

I know this isn't what you asked for (locking the post) and is not something that will have an immediate impact, but we hope to see a significant reduction in suggested edit spam over the next few weeks.

Comment: "I know this isn't what you asked for" [If you say so...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346454/if-the-author-says-its-not-an-answer-can-we-take-their-word-for-it)

Comment: Why do it? Spam edits enough and see (a question about) your spam appear in the "Hot meta posts" section :-)

Comment: I don't understand your comment, @TripeHound

Comment: You asked why spammers would repeatedly spam suggested edits they know will get rejected. A slightly tongue-in-cheek (though not impossible) reason is that after doing it enough, someone will ask a question on meta about it, which hits the "Hot Meta Posts" block on every SO page and probably gets their spam seen by more people than would ever have seen the spammed-version of the original post if the edit had been accepted.

Comment: Well, I also provided a reason for them to do so (which I guess you missed), @TripeHound - and given how spammers do operate, your scenario is fairly... imaginative...

Comment: Can you, and if so will you, purge the timeline of that answer as well as the review pages on these kind of suggested edit spams?

Comment: @Adriaan - there's a history there. Purging it means we lose that history. These are pages that are rarely accessed and only by registered users of certain reputation - I don't see a good reason to remove them.

Comment: Personally, I would use these examples as review audits. Is there a way that the system can "generate" audits the same way these spammers opperate?

Comment: @Braiam I wrote a feature request for a general tool for that a while back: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272472/better-review-audits-better-review-ban-tools

Comment: @Braiam Why bother? Just put a few dozen of the ones on that post into the audit cycle.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes we had asked to allow us to use custom audits, but I remember that it was rejected on the basis that we need the post to be "fresh".

Comment: @oded: Just wondering why the timeline page (or the review queue item page) is *public* in the first place :-? Is there a value for anonymous users there?

Comment: @Abhitalks - what's the value it not making it public? Anonymous may be someone who has an account, but isn't logged in, you know.

Comment: "*Anonymous may be someone who has an account*" -- Hmmmm... Yes. Thanks @Oded.

Comment: Actually, regarding @Abhitalks's comment, why *are* suggested edits publicly visible? If you made them visible only to logged-in users (and to the user who suggested the edit, if anonymous), you'd presumably completely eliminate their usefulness as "proof-of-spam" pages. And I don't really see any practical need for those pages to be shown to anybody who didn't contribute the edit and cannot (even in principle) review it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen "and to the user who suggested the edit, if anonymous" ...How would you tell who they are? They're ANONYMOUS.

Comment: @Feathercrown cookies

Comment: @TylerH I guess... But then couldn't other people using the same computer see the review queue without logging in? I guess it's not TOO much of a problem....

Comment: @Feathercrown If a user's not logged in, that just means actions they take on the site will show up to others as having been done by "anonymous user". However, if they've logged in before, it's possible for Stack Overflow the website to track that and assign certain things to the session based on those cookies.

Comment: @TylerH: You don't even need to have ever logged in before. As soon as you visit SO, you receive a persistent cookie (the one I got when I just tested this is marked as expiring in January 2055) that contains a unique ID. It's easy to test this by visiting SO in incognito / private browsing mode and looking at the cookies you receive.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Right, I mean that if the user has logged in, cookies can link the anonymous user to an existing user account. This also means if the anonymous user ever logs in in the future as well. Of course a cookie can be used to track an anonymous user who never logs in, it just won't be able to tie that anonymous user to an existing user account.

Comment: @Oded FYI, [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23503186/timeline) just got suggest-edited with spam a few more times.

Comment: @Pang - that will of course happen. If they use automated tools (and even if they are not), it is very possible they hadn't adjusted yet to the new measure. We do not expect an immediate response - it will take a while.

Comment: @Oded your measure seems to only block links in edits where ALL the rejects reasons are spam. Maybe a majority would be enough. Also why are [cases like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15942119) not blocked?

Comment: I just revisited the timeline of the post; spam seems to have stopped in May 2017, so I guess your measures worked. Good job!