# Is it rude/abusive to knowingly abuse the answer section?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer, rude-or-abusive

Every once in a while going through the VLQ queue, I'll notice a new question posted as an answer that's prefaced with "I know that this isn't an answer, but..." (I'll occasionally even see this from people who have enough more than enough rep to know better). For example, from a user with 350+ reputation:

[image]

Can these be flagged for moderator attention or flagged as rude or abusive (since the person is obviously knowingly violating site rules), or should they just be handled by the normal VLQ queue process?

Comment: Kinda depends on context.  If it's really just a comment thinly veiled as an answer then yes; if it's actually enough to stand on its own two legs without the disclaimer, then no.  In the latter case, edit the answer to remove the red herring.

Comment: @Makoto In this case, it was a completely new question that, by the poster's own admission, made absolutely no effort to answer the original question.

Comment: There's a different flag for that, "not an answer". You should stick to the right flag for the situation. You can be flag banned if you do it wrong often enough.

Comment: See [If the author says it's not an answer, can we take their word for it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346454/4639281)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd only apply the "rude and abusive" flag for something truly abusive, like insults, trolling, and content that was intended to be offensive. These flags shoot to the top of our queue, and can carry heavy penalties if approved, so we're pretty careful in accepting these. I'd most likely decline an offensive flag on an answer that was just a guess.

If you're seeing this in the Low Quality Posts review queue, I'd just rely on that queue to act on it. Reviewers seem to be doing a pretty good job of handling these without moderator intervention, particularly since the review voting thresholds were lowered.

If it's a clear non-answer, like the one you show above, a "not an answer" flag should be fine. Either review or moderators will take care of it at that point.

I should point out that sometimes people are a little too self-deprecating and will say "I don't think this is an answer, but" and follow that with an actual answer. Sometimes, people just aren't confident in their answer, so make sure you read the rest of the answer to make sure. This isn't the case in the one you highlight above.

Comment: Answers that were a guess or are clearly wrong [shouldn't be flagged as VLQ or non-answers either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality?rq=1), though, right?

Comment: One other prescribed use of the abusive flag: [Cats are not allowed to walk across keyboards as part of Stack Exchange posts; this is abuse and should be flagged as such.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/288751)

Comment: @TinyGiant I think it was recently discussed at MSO in more details: [Why was my abusive flag on a post containing only gibberish declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342855/839601) (tl;dr undecipherable gibberish also qualifies as abusive just like in the MSE post you referred)