# Answer that doesn't answer the question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, specific-answer

In this answer, the user specifically states that the answer doesn't answer what was asked. Since it is an answer but not to the question asked, should it be flagged and which flag should be used?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22523744

Comment: No, because it is an answer. Feel free to downvote an answer that doesn't work for you, but don't flag it as NAA.

Comment: @honk I updated the question a little. It may not matter with the update but I'm not sure.

Comment: @honk the user doesn't say that his answer is wrong, but that he ignores the question and decided to answer something else. Is like if I ask you for apples and you give me orange, you aren't giving me what I'm asking for.

Comment: @honk There's a *world* of difference between someone attempting to answer the question asked, but misunderstanding the question and as a result, failing to answer the question asked, and someone *knowingly* posting an answer that doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: @Servy: I wasn't aware up to now that there is a difference. But if it is, I'm learning something new today :)

Comment: @Honk A good question relating to that difference is [Can we add 'off topic' to the list of answer flags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377539/7795130)

Comment: @CodyGray Well that's not what the rules on NAA, or basically all of the official guidance on the subject says.  The rule is that a post is NAA if it's not an *attempt* to answer the question.  Whether they succeed or fail to answer the question is irrelevant (to it being NAA), what's relevant is that they're intending to answer it.

Comment: Related [If the author says it's not an answer, can we take their word for it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346454/if-the-author-says-its-not-an-answer-can-we-take-their-word-for-it)

Answer (score -3):

I believe that for answers that are *clearly* not answering the question asked and aren't even *trying* to solve the OP's problem, the Not an Answer flag can be used.

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

All this fits in. It was posted as an answer, but does not attempt to answer the question it was posted on. It would sometimes make sense as a comment, and sometimes it just needs to be deleted.

In the specific case you mentioned, the answerer literally said:

> The following **doesn't answer what was asked**

This makes it totally crystal clear that the answer doesn't actually answer the question asked, or even try to. It fits the NAA flag description perfectly. I left a comment telling the answerer not to do this in the future and flagged as NAA. This is what you should do in the future.

Comment: It does give a way to format data as tabulated though. Did you try the answer?

Comment: @ryanyuyu sometimes that's true and it's necessary to leave a comment or custom flag the post. But in this case, the answer clearly did not answer the question. Even without domain knowledge, you could tell that pretty clearly.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard except it did. you should have tried it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu What domain knowledge is this relying on?  The user said, in their post, that it wasn't an attempt to answer the question.  No domain knowledge necessary.

Comment: @Servy the one needed to realize it still, to a low extent, was doing what was asked in the question.

Comment: @Servy I misread what you wrote.  I didn't see the first revision and assumed you meant a commentor on the answer as "the user" instead of the answer's actual author.

Answer (score -3):

You gave too much credit to the poster's text. The answer did give a way to generate formatted data in a table, even though it was very much less than optimal. Maybe try the actual answers next time you encounter such a situation.